# Lambda doesn't close over object in With statement

Tags: vb.net, lambda, with-statement

I came across a pretty interesting quirk concerning the interaction of lambda function closures and the VB `With` statement today. Here is a short code snippet to demonstrate the issue (I've tried to keep it as minimal as possible), followed by an overview of what I think the problem is:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim someList = New List(Of String),
            myInvoker As Invoker

        With someList
            Dim listFiller = Sub()
                                 .Add("Hello") '<- This is where the problem is
                             End Sub

            myInvoker = New Invoker(listFiller)
        End With

        myInvoker.Invoke()
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", someList))
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module

'This is just an object that accepts a delegate and invokes it when told to
Public Class Invoker
    Public Delegate Sub ArbitraryDelegate()
    Private _ArbitraryCallBack As ArbitraryDelegate

    Public Sub Invoke()
        _ArbitraryCallBack.Invoke()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(arbitraryCallback As ArbitraryDelegate)
        _ArbitraryCallBack = arbitraryCallback
    End Sub
End Class
```

Basically, I am creating an instance of a reference type (a `List(Of String)` in this case, but it can be anything), storing it in a variable, then using it in a `With` statement. The trouble arises when I create a lambda function that accesses a method of this object using just `.Add`. Once I've created the lambda function, I pass it to some external object to invoke at a later time.

Unfortunately, when the external object tries to invoke the lambda function it was given, it runs into a `System.NullReferenceException`, because the lambda expression (for whatever reason) failed to close over `subList`. If I explicitly write `subList.Add("Hello")`, it works again. As far as I can see, the two scenarios should behave equivalently, since there are no ambiguous interpretations for the line beginning with `.Add`.

My question is whether this is a bug in how the With statement is implemented, or if I'm missing something and this is expected behavior.